# Method that takes array parameter

Tags: c#, api, api-design, optimization

I want to implement two methods: `AddPlayers` and `AddPlayer`. Is it better when `AddPlayers` calls `AddPlayer` or `AddPlayer` calls `AddPlayers` with a single item array? Is there a significant difference in performance and IL output?

```
// AddPlayers contains the logic
void AddPlayer(Player player)
{
    return AddPlayers(new [] { player });
}
```

vs

```
// AddPlayer contains the logic
void AddPlayers(IEnumerable<Player> players)
{
    foreach (var player in players)
    {
        AddPlayer(player);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd ask 2 questions:

1. Which choice results in more readable code?
2. Will either choice give you an *obvious* optimization opportunity, based on expected use cases?
   Gnat's right in his comment about micro-optimization but if you're adding 100,000 players at once, you're going to want the logic in `AddPlayers` (with a bulk insert).  You'll also want a comment in `AddPlayer` warning the developer not to call it in a loop.

In a more typical situation (adding perhaps at most a dozen players at a time) then it likely doesn't matter much which option you choose.

Comment: In my opinion 2nd choice. And I think it will be more performant too but it depends

Comment: @Konrad: It depends on whether you measure it or not.

Comment: *"if you're adding 100,000 players at once, you're going to want the logic in AddPlayers (with a bulk insert)"*, in case you know for sure each single call of `AddPlayer` needs some noteable time, because it produces some database insert. If it just adds an object in-memory to a list, there may be no measurable performance difference, however. So you should always measure, at least make a rough estimation.